# How to use SQLite c interface library in android

Tags: android, c++, sqlite, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am using http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html as a reference for using the sqlite c for opening the db

i m calling like this

```
    package com.example.offline;

    public class NativeLib {

    static {
    System.loadLibrary("sqlite3");
    }

    public native int sqlite3_open(String filename,Object sqlite3);

    }
```

As documentation says

```
    int sqlite3_open(
    const char *filename,   /* Database filename (UTF-8) */
    sqlite3 **ppDb          /* OUT: SQLite db handle */
    );
```

Error in logcat

```
12-12 14:49:15.645: W/dalvikvm(3265): No implementation found for native Lcom/example/offline/NativeLib;.sqlite3_open:(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)I
```

So my question is can we create sqlite c object in our java

Here is  my Android.mk file

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := sqlite3
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := sqlite3.c
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Thanx guys

Comment: C interface will not work, methods are not even exposed. Exposed SQLite interface is wrapped in [SQLiteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html).

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523067/sqlite-with-android-ndk ?

Comment: Why log says native method not found     12-12 16:50:48.980: E/AndroidRuntime(2094): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.shabdkosh.offline.NativeLib.sqlite3_open:(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)I

Comment: Going to C, you must compile sqlite3.c in you NDK and somehow (I don't know) expose interface in JNI.

Comment: Thanks @LS_dev but i have successfully created .so(binary) file by using ndk after that only i got the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what's your jni method?call native sqlite3_open(String filename,Object sqlite3) can not find language c sqlite3_open(const char *filename,sqlite3 **ppDb).

Comment: ur saying correct is there any other way to call the sqlite3_open(const char *filename,sqlite3 **ppDb).

Comment: you need to know how to write jni.it's not very hard.search in google and do it.however the easy way to write jni,you can use swig.