# How to upgrade SQLite version?

Tags: android, sqlite, version, upgrade

I'm developing my first app and using the following code I see what is my SQLite version:

```
Cursor cursor = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(":memory:", null).rawQuery("select sqlite_version() AS sqlite_version", null);
String sqliteVersion = "";
while(cursor.moveToNext())
    sqliteVersion += cursor.getString(0);
Log.e("Version", sqliteVersion);
```

My version is 3.7.11.

Since I need to use some new features, how to upgrade it to the latest version?

Answer (score 1):

The SQLite library that you access with `SQLiteDatabase` is part of Android and cannot be replaced (unless you recompile Android on a rooted device).

You have to [compile your own copy of SQLite with the NDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523067/sqlite-with-android-ndk) and access it through your own wrapper functions/objects.

Comment: Even i do it on my phone, how to make my app compatible for all devices? So SQLite version is related to phone, i tought that i depends on Android SDK...

Comment: What you compile with the NDK gets shippe with your app.